# Using global function in vuejs. linter (?)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, eslint

I have to use a javascript library (emailJS) to send email from my vuejs application. The problem is that this library create a global function and when I try to use the function, eslint notify me about this funcion is not defined.

Is posible to wrap this funtion into a javascript module to use on the components?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes globals simply cannot be avoided (I'm looking at you, `gapi`). Just add it to your eslint `globals` config.

In `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  globals: {
    SmtpClient: true // or whatever the global variable is named
  }
}
```

See http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals